# how to fix damaged wall after peeling off hook?

Tags: walls, painting

[image: damage]
[image: damage 2]
[image: damage 3]

How would I go on repairing damage caused by peeling off some "damage free" adhesive sticky hooks? Photos attached. It looks like a layer of paint came off completely. Would I need a layer of filler or primer or should I just paint over it?

Thank you and please be patient, I am absolutely useless with this.
I am also not sure about which shade of white my walls are painted in either.

Comment: Damage-free sticky hooks use a complex mechanism that must be used as directed.  Usually, they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of us have been there. Just get yourself a small tub of spackle or joint compound and dab it on with a brush or sponge. Let it dry and then rub it down with a damp cloth if it's too lumpy or spiky. Apply a second time if it's not filled and textured to your liking.

Once that's done you can prime and paint.